# Syntax error when trying to import Cntlr from arelle module

Tags: python, anaconda, xbrl, arelle

My goal is to use Arelle (open-source platform for XBRL community) to parse XBRL docs from the SEC.

I am following instructions found [here](https://xbrlnexus.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/xbrl-zoo-anaconda-arelle-pandas-python/).

I successfully git cloned Arelle's [code](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle) into the  `Lib` directory of Anaconda. However, when I try `from arelle import Cntlr` I get the following syntax error.

`File "arelle\Cntlr.py", line 573
    print(logEntry, file=file)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I am using Python 2.7.12. in Anaconda.

Any feedback is appreciated and I can provide further information upon request.

Comment: Arelle uses Python 3. This is mentioned in the instructions you were following.

Comment: @user2357112: the `setup.py` file uses lib3to2 to install under Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I see it does. It looks like the instructions the questioner is following bypass `setup.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions you found are rather old (from 2014), and appear to be outdated.

I was able to install the package with the following steps:

```
# This is needed because the 3to2 library can't be installed as an egg; if
# you don't install it with `pip` first the installation of Arelle will fail.
$ pip install 3to2
# Install Arelle directly from GitHub, this will take a while
$ pip install git+https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle
```

With `3to2` installed, the installation script `setup.py` proceeds to translate the Arelle sourcecode back to a Python 2 compatible form. Translation takes several minutes, be patient.

Comment: When I used the pip install I got ``error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized``. But git clone worked perfectly. Really appreciate your guidance @Martijn Pieters.

Comment: @p_sutherland: sounds like you have an older `setuptools` version installed somewhere. Use `pip install -U setuptools` to clear that error (I think, see [What does "error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized" indicate?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14296531)).